# Sending email via oh-mailer on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, phpmailer

I want to send email to authenticate email entered in an HTML registration form. I am using php mailer. Can someone tell me how to tweak the following credentials in order to achieve the same.

```
<?php
include('phpmailer.php');
class Mail extends PhpMailer
{
 // Set default variables for all new objects
 public $From     = 'noreply@domain.com';
 public $FromName = '';
 public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 public $Mailer   = 'smtp';
 public $SMTPAuth = true;
 public $Username = '';
 public $Password = '';
 public $SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 public $WordWrap = 75;

public function subject($subject)
{
    $this->Subject = $subject;
}

public function body($body)
{
    $this->Body = $body;
}

public function send()
{
    $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
    $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
    return parent::send();
}
```

}

Comment: You can find your solution here at : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-an-email-using-phpmailer/amp/

Comment: thanks, I haven't tried it yet but it seems self explanatory and quite brief.

Comment: Only problem is that I need to send email to email-id entered by the user. That means it should be variable. How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t say what your problem is, so I can only provide a generic answer.

First of all it looks like you’re running a very old version of PHPMailer, and that you’ve based your code on an old example, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Base your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer, and fill in your own credentials.

That should be all you need — if you run into trouble, be sure to read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

Comment: I agree with @Synchro. you are running on old system. php mailer work on smtp details. But most importantly before filling any make sure your provided details of gamil ID has less secure option ON.: https://youtu.be/AFRqT3BR_e0